# Pass-through mouse click on label to the parent element

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to make label pass-through click event? For now I just disabled the label and it works fine but color of text has dimmed, though forecolor is pure black. Is there a way to set color to normal? Or maybe there is better way to pass-through clicks through label?

**Edit to clarify**
It's Windows Forms and i need to perform click on a control under the label.

Sorry, I will tag questions more clearly :)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Comment: Assuming Winforms and also that you know the parent control of these labels you can simply assign them to the very Clicked event of that Parent..

Comment: OK. Did you understand my suggestion? Assign the Clicked event of that parent also to all the Labels! (Copy the event name, then select all Labels and past into the Click slot in their event pane!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try this :

```
  label.Click -= label_Click;
```

As you know `+=` crates an event , so , if i replace `+` with a `-`,the result is obvious right ?

**UPDATE**

I don't quiet get the term `pass through click` but if it is that u have a control beneath the label and u want to rather perform click on that,isn't it obvious to do something like this ?

```
  private void beneathControl_click()
   {
  allCodesInAnotherMethod();
    }

  private void label_click()
  {
  allCodesInAnotherMethod();
   }


  private void allCodesInAnotherMethod()
  {
   ///all codes here
  }
```

Comment: Who said there even was a Click event for the Label?

Comment: in winforms theres always a click event

Comment: sorry for saying `always` , but why did u even ask if label has a click event wen it really does ?

Comment: Well, the code compiles and would remove a ckick event from the handler, had there been one; but the issue is that the Label still blocks the click from going to the control below..

Comment: wait what ??? control below ????? when did OP say it ?? let me check and edit my answer

Comment: hehe, title? last line?. see my advice to the op : label.Click += parent_Click;

Comment: please rechk my answer and see if this is what OP wants ?

Comment: Most likely but only he can tell. I would avoid calling the allCodesInAnotherMethod and instead call (or assign/hook up to) beneathControl_click itself, reducing dependencies.

Comment: or why not use `performClick` for the beneath control ?

Comment: Well that would work for Button but not e.g. for a Chart, Panel, PictureBox etc..

Comment: i wonder why isn't the post downvoted ? not even an inch is clear

Comment: yes. After four hours he should check back and clarify. Sometimes newbies get away with it; esp. on an Easter Sunday ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want whatever is positioned beneath the label to be clicked instead of the label, and that you're using WPF, you can just set the [`IsHitTestVisible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible?view=netframework-4.7.1) property of the label to false.

Comment: WPF: Quite an assumption ;-)

Comment: @TaW: The main alternative has been effectively deprecated for over 10 years. Either way, the OP should have tagged their question.

Comment: _deprecated_ Well they tried but it still carries the vast majority of all new projects. It is one of those things, that will never go away.